# RESTful service contracts

Tags: rest, service, protocol-buffers, rpc

We are designing an application and want to use (micro)services. We think that it would be good to enforce the APIs and contracts between services.

Protobuf and similar technologies can do this, but they are all RPC, not REST. Are there any similar technologies for REST APIs? Should we just switch to RPC instead?

**EDIT: More Details**

With hypermedia + REST you can decouple the API, but I want to explicitly validate that it matches the consumer's requirements. So there would be some file (kind of like a Java interface) that says what is expected, and some compiler checks to see if the API conforms, so you know if you broke a consumer when you make changes.

This is how protobuf works, but it is RPC only. I'm wondering if there is something similar for REST

Comment: Feel free to recommend a better stack exchange site for this question. I couldn't find one that fit very well.

Comment: Can you add more details to the question? What language? What does protobuf do, and why isn't it good in your case? If I understand well, the contract between a REST service and a REST client can always change, so you have to always parse the hypermedia response, and extract the hyperlinks if you want to do anything with a REST service (unless you use cache ofc.)...

Comment: Right so with hypermedia + REST you can decouple the API, but I want to explicitly validate that it matches the consumer's requirements. So there's some file (kind of like a Java interface) that says what is expected, and some compiler checks to see if the API conforms, so you know if you broke a consumer when you make changes.

Comment: Protobuf does this, but it's RPC only. I'm wondering if there is something similar for REST.

Comment: The problem that REST is still in a maturing phase. There are many hypermedia types with different approaches, and some of the service providers use a dedicated vendor specific media type, so it is very hard to do something general, like your e2e testing system. I think currently hydra is the best option: http://www.hydra-cg.com/ it will become a standard soon, but it still does not cover every related topic, e.g. ad-hoc query link description is not solved. So I don't think you will find what you are looking for, but that's just my opinion.